# SQL Server search between numbers in varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Invoices` with `InvoiceNumber` as `varchar(32)`

The customer can modify how will be their invoices format, like: `INV00001`, `000001`, `I00001`, etc., so when it's configured, the program each time that is created a invoice it will increment the invoice number so it can be unique

I would like to search invoices but using integer values like from: 2 to 10, like this:

`SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE InvoiceNumber >= '2' AND InvoiceNumber <= '10'`

How I can do that with a `varchar` field?

**EDIT:** Customer set the format like they want and most of them never change it, most of them use three chars and the rest numbers like: `INV0000001`

This is not my database, I'm just developing an addon for this app, can't change anything in the DB

```
InvoiceNumber
-------------
INV00260
INV00261
INV00262
INV00263
INV00264
INV00265
INV00266
INV00267
INV00268
```

A customer want to search invoice using a between values, let's say he wants to search invoice between `INV00262` and `INV00267`, the customer wants to search by the number, the result should be:

```
INV00262
INV00263
INV00264
INV00265
INV00266
INV00267
```

But using integer values like: `WHERE InvoiceNumber >= '262' AND InvoiceNumber <= '267'`

Comment: If you want to treat the value as an integer then you should store it as an integer. Apply the formatting in the presentation layer, not the DB layer.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your InvoceNmber contains  valid integer values  just stored  as  string ..

You could cast as INT the string eg:

`SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE cast(InvoiceNumber AS INT)>= 2 AND InvoiceNumber <= 10`

Comment: What would happen if you cast `'INV00001'` to an `int`? What is that numerically equivalent to?

Comment: I don't know if the the OP have this problems .. @Igor  you should ask to OP  ..  for this  ..  looking to sample provided .. i have proposed   my answer

Comment: `Assuming that your InvoceNmber contains valid integer values just stored as string` <= they are not. `The customer can modify how will be their invoices format, like: INV00001, 000001, I00001, etc` <= from the question. 2 of the 3 are not valid integers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a more effective use of indexes would work this way. Compare query plans with the accepted answer to see if there's a big difference.

```
select * from T
where InvoiceNumber between
    'INV' + right('0000' + cast(<start> as varchar(5)) and
    'INV' + right('0000' + cast( <end>  as varchar(5));
```

It's also a bit simpler and the arguments only need to be referenced once which can make a difference in client code.

Comment: @tttony I don't quite follow. That's incredibly simple and it's all done with SQL.

Comment: @ttony You need to ask questions that represent the full problem.